Highcharts chart is showing but Highcharts Pattern Fill library is not working
I am trying to use the Highcharts Pattern Fill library in my Vue 3 app. I've followed the instructions and the chart shows but the pattern fill does not. What am I doing wrong?
Codepen here: https://codepen.io/epatmalnieksge/pen/YzmOazG
<template>
  <div id="container"></div>
</template>

<script>
import Highcharts from "https://esm.sh/highcharts";
import HighchartsPatternFill from "https://esm.sh/highcharts-pattern-fill";

HighchartsPatternFill(Highcharts);

export default {
  mounted() {
    Highcharts.chart("container", {
      chart: {
        type: "column"
      },
      title: {
        text: "Pattern Fill Example"
      },
      series: [
        {
          data: [1, 3, 2, 4],
          color: {
            pattern: {
              path: {
                d: "M 10 0 L 0 10 M -5 5 L 5 15 M 15 -5 L 25 5",
                strokeWidth: 2
              },
              width: 10,
              height: 10
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    });
  }
};
</script>



Which guide did you follow for this plugin? The docs state a different thing https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-design-and-style/pattern-fills . And you seem to use some deprecated package https://github.com/highcharts/pattern-fill

I tried numerous things and don't want to use the CDN. Is there a way to do this via npm? The deprecated package is from codepen. If I npm install the pattern fills package in my app I get the same thing shown in my codepen example.

highcharts-pattern-fill package isn't supposed to be installed. I posted the answer

highcharts-pattern-fill is deprecated legacy package for older Highchart versions. The official documentation doesn't recommend it. Instead it says that builtin module should be used:
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/pattern-fill.js"></script>

Which corresponds to this import, which is explained here:
import Highcharts from 'highcharts';
import PatternFill from 'highcharts/modules/pattern-fill';
PatternFill(Highcharts);


I switched to the CDN and it worked, thanks

To include the pattern-fill module in Highcharts, you can load it directly from the following URL:
https://code.highcharts.com/modules/pattern-fill.src.js


is there no way to do this via npm?

The module is available in basic Highcharts, you just need to import it properly in your project, like in my answer or like that for example: require('highcharts/modules/pattern-fill')(Highcharts);
